# Скопировать часть байтов из файла c#

Tags: c#, byte

Есть файл 3.exe, в котором записаны еще 2 файла : 1.ехе и 2.ехе (побайтно в конец дописал), нужно "вытащить" отдельно 1.ехе и 2.ехе, в этом вся сложность. 1.ехе можно получить таким путем : начиная копировать от веса 3.ехе без этих 2 файлов и до начала 2.ехе, копирование 2.ехе аналогично. Но тут вся сложность, как понять, где начинается 2.ехе ? была идея записывать в конец файла размер 3.ехе без этих 2 файлов + размер 1.ехе, тем самым получим начало файла 2.ехе, но максимальное значение 255 и ничего не вышло, записывается 0. Можете подсказать, как лучше реализовать ?

Надеюсь, что я доступно объяснил, если нет, то пишите, попробую по-другому.

Пример кода :

```
var fil2 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"2.exe");
var fil1 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"1.exe");

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"bin.exe", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{

    fs.Write(fil2, 0, fil2.Length);

    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
var rezd = new byte[4] { 5, 55, 56, (byte)fil2.Length };

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"bin.exe", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{

    fs.Write(fil1, 0, fil1.Length);
    fs.Write(rezd, 0, rezd.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: Я бы искал сигнатуру exe-файла.

Comment: "...Надеюсь, что я доступно объяснил..." - как бы это помягче сказать - короче,  перед глазами возник Иван Бездомный, пишущий объяснение как Берлиозу трамвай отрезал голову.

Comment: Ну и поскольку Вы сами пишите, сами читаете, то в начале файла можно организовать блок фиксированной длины, в котором записано количество файлов и их длина.

Comment: "но максимальное значение 255 и ничего не вышло" - вот этот перл объясните подробнее

Comment: @Qwertiy а можно пример ?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов а как записать значение, которое превышает 255 ?

Comment: @Igor байт принимает максимальное значение 255, т.к я записываю по байтно в конец файла, то немного проблематично записать длину файла

Comment: я видимо чего-то не знаю, можете мне помочь ?

Comment: @Lolidze, пример: `MZђ`.

Comment: @Qwertiy а как с ним работать ? если открыть в текстовом редакторе ехе, то кол-во MZђ будет = кол-ву ехе в файле, тобишь скопировать от MZђ до MZђ и вставить новый файл получится выделить определенный ехе ? там же кодировки и тп , можете чуть по подробнее объяснить ?

Comment: @Lolidze, маловероятно. Но сигнатура exe более интересная и можно что-то на основе сигнатур замутить.

Comment: например ? ибо у меня в голову ничего не лезет :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать `BinaryWriter` поверх файлового потока. Не совсем уверен, что у вас там за байты в `rezd`, но в целом код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var fil2 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"2.exe");
var fil1 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"1.exe");

using (var fs = new FileStream(@"bin.exe", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Write(fil2, 0, fil2.Length);
}

var rezd = new byte[] { 5, 55, 56 };

using (var fs = new FileStream(@"bin.exe", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.Write(fil1);
        writer.Write(rezd);
        writer.Write(fil2.Length);
    }
}
```

Вы используете `using`, так что ручные вызовы `Flush`/`Close` не нужны.

Comment: спасибо, rezd чисто для меня, чтоб я ориентировался в hex editor. Теперь в конец файла записались 4 байта (после rezd) 0 108 0 0 (смотрел на char dec), длина fil2.Length = 27648

Comment: и как мне получить именно 27648 ? мне же нужно знать до куда копировать байты, откуда и тп

Comment: @Lolidze при чтении - отмотать читающий стрим до позиции (общая длина -4), открыть поверх него BinaryReader, и прочитать оттуда эти 4 байта вызовом ReadInt32

Comment: да, спасибо, все получилось

Comment: вот об этом я не подумал :( как получить доступ к своим же ресурсам, когда программа открыта ?  BinaryReader fss = new BinaryReader(File.Open(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, FileMode.Open));

Comment: @Lolidze вирус пишете? :) задайте отдельным вопросом :)

Comment: вирус ? на c# ? этж не практично и не логично )) задал, уже ответили, спасибо большое за помощь !