# побайтно прочитать файл, когда он открыт C#

Tags: c#, byte

Моя история тянется с [прошлой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624139/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-c#624139):

нужно прочитать байты из своей же сборки (exe), но т.к она исполняется, доступ запрещен (файл используется другим процессом).

```
  var assemblyPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
  var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(assemblyPath, FileMode.Open));
```

Как все-таки прочитать байты ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте более подробный вариант `File.Open`

```
var reader = new BinaryReader(
  File.Open(assemblyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
);
```